# facebook user inforamtion along with contact number

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I needed facebook user info in my app. For it I have used "https://graph.facebook.com/me&access_token=%@" I am getting user info properly. But unable to get the contact number of user via graph API. Can't we retrieve contact number of user from Facebook? Please help me.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but we can't retrieve the Contact Number of the User through the Graph API as the contact number is not exposed to present APIs.

**Update**

The removal of this data has also been mentioned in this [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/447/).

Comment: Is any other way to retrieve the contact number @Anvesh Saxena

Comment: Retrieving the contact number from API is not an option, although you can always ask the user for the same.